How can I break equation in forest?
Based on this answer, I want to break the equation at
\text{I run well \\and II don't run well}.
But the equation doesn' break.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows.meta}
\newcommand\engnum[1]{\ifcase#1
    %zero
    \or
    %one
    \or 
    %two
    \or
    %three
    \or
Probability
    \or
Result
    \or
    six
    \or
    seven
    \or
    eight
    \or
    nine
    \fi}
\begin{document}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{0.8}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ab}{0.6}  
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\notab}{0.6}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\anotb}{1-\ab}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\nota}{1-\a}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\notanotb}{1-\notab}
    \begin{landscape}   
        \begin{forest}
            for tree={
                % nodes
                draw, rounded corners=2pt,
                if level=0{circle}{minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1.3cm},
                top color=white, bottom color=blue!20,
                math content,
                alias/.wrap pgfmath arg={l-#1}{level},
                % tree
                grow'=east,
                edge = {-Stealth,semithick},
                child anchor=west,
                l sep'=12mm,
                if level=1{s sep'=10mm}{s sep'=10mm},% insert different `s sep`
                tier/.option = level,
            },
            for leaves={!u.l sep'+=5mm},
            /tikz/ELS/.style = {% Edge Label Style
                pos=0.5, sloped, font=\footnotesize,
                inner sep=2pt, anchor=#1},
            EL/.style = {%
                if n=1{% Edge Label, automatic positioned
                    edge label={node[ELS=south]{$#1$}}}
                {edge label={node[ELS=north]{$#1$}}},
            },
            ELT/.style 2 args = {%
                if n=1{% Edge Label, automatic positioned
                    edge label={node[ELS=south]{$\num{#1}\times\num{#2}$}}}
                {edge label={node[ELS=north]{$\num{#1}\times\num{#2}$}}},
                if n children=0{%
                    delay={content={\pgfmathparse{(#1*#2)}\pgfqkeys{/pgf/number format}{fixed,precision=4,use comma}{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}}},
                }{},
            },
            before typesetting nodes={%
                for descendants={content+={\llap{\phantom{$\overline{X}$}}}},
            }
            [
            [\text{I run well},     EL=\num{\a}
            [\text{II run well},     EL=\num{\ab},
            [\text{I and II run well},
            [,ELT={\a}{\ab} %= \num{0.14}
            ]
            ]
            ]
            [\text{II don't run well},   EL=\num{\anotb},
            [
            \text{I run well \\and II don't run well},
            [, ELT={\a}{\anotb}%=\num{0.06}
            ]
            ]
            ]
            ]
            [\text{I don't run well},   EL=\num{\nota}
            [\text{II run well},     EL=\num{\notab}
            [\text{I run well  and  II run well}
            [, ELT={\nota}{\notab}]
            ]
            ]
            [\text{II don't run well},   EL=\num{\notanotb}
            [\text{I and II don't run well}
            [, ELT={\nota}{\notanotb}]
            ]
            ]
            ]
            ]
            \path ([yshift=1.5ex]current bounding box.north) coordinate (N);
            % 0.5ex can be changed to increase/decreas the vertical distance between the
            % level indicators and the tree
            \foreach \X  in {0,...,4}
            {\node[anchor=base,font=\strut\footnotesize\sffamily] at 
                (l-\X.center |-N){\engnum{\the\numexpr\X+1}};}
        \end{forest}
    \end{landscape} 
    
\end{document} 



unrelated to any of the code in your example, \text is like \mbox and is single line so \text{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}I run well \\and II don't run well\end{tabular}}

when I said you needed math content to avoid the error, I meant the other tree needed it because it included nodes with overline etc. so, in that case, not using it would need $ ... $ everywhere, whereas, in this case, it's rather the opposite.

Not related but in 3rd column 'probability' 3rd case, you wrote that "I run well" although "I don't run well".

In the earlier example, the content of the nodes contained maths, so math content was required to avoid wrapping every node's contents in $...$. In this case, using the same option requires wrapping everything in \text. Better to use math content only for the leaves, which actually contain maths.
For line breaking, I recommend align=<col spec> where <col spec> specifies the columns of the tabular you want. While egreg's method will work, it is unnecessary and can easily lead to implicitly nested tabulars where nesting serves no purpose. For centring, align=@{}c@{} or align=c are probably what you want. Below I use the former. Use the latter if you want a bit more horizontal padding.
The following illustrates three ways of adapting the tree, all of which avoid drawing edges from the rounded corners.
There is no benefit to automating this tree, really, since the content of the nodes does not itself provide the probabilities required to calculate the result. If you want to use pgfmath to do this, however, either pick better macro names or do the calculations in a local environment. Using \pgfmathset ... \a ... at the top level of the document environment is equivalent to doing \def\a ... and will overwrite existing definitions without warning. Although it duplicates computations in the example below, adding it to a forest tree with TeX is one option. (You probably don't want it actually to be part of a style such as probability tree in your real document unless you only have one tree using that style.)
Minor tidying:

Alternative alignment:

Forked edges:

\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\forestset{%
  probability tree/.style={%
    TeX={%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{0.8}%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\ab}{0.6}  %
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\notab}{0.6}%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\anotb}{1-\ab}%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\nota}{1-\a}%
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\notanotb}{1-\notab}%
    },
    for tree={
      % nodes
      draw, rounded corners=2pt,
      if level=0{circle}{minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1.3cm},
      top color=white, bottom color=blue!20,
      l sep'=10mm,
      if n children=0{math content,!u.l sep'=15mm,
      }{
        align=@{}c@{},
        if n children=1{calign=child edge}{},
      },
      alias/.process={Ow{level}{l-##1}},
      % tree
      grow'=east,
      edge = {-Stealth,semithick},
      tier/.option = level,
    },
  },
  /tikz/ELS/.style = {% Edge Label Style
    pos=0.5,
    sloped,
    font=\footnotesize,
    inner sep=2pt,
  anchor=#1},
  EL/.style = {%
    if n=1{% Edge Label, automatic positioned
    edge label={node[ELS=south]{$#1$}}}
    {edge label={node[ELS=north]{$#1$}}},
  },
  ELT/.style 2 args = {%
    if n=1{% Edge Label, automatic positioned
    edge label={node[ELS=south]{$\num{#1}\times\num{#2}$}}}
    {edge label={node[ELS=north]{$\num{#1}\times\num{#2}$}}},
    if n children=0{%
      delay={content={\pgfmathparse{(#1*#2)}\pgfqkeys{/pgf/number format}{fixed,precision=4,use comma}{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}}},
    }{},
  },
}%
\begin{forest}%
  probability tree,
  for tree={%
    child anchor=west,
  },
  [
    [I run well,     EL=\num{\a}
      [II run well,     EL=\num{\ab},
        [I and II run well,
          [,ELT={\a}{\ab} %= \num{0.14}
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [II don't run well,   EL=\num{\anotb},
        [
          I run well \\and II don't run well,
          [, ELT={\a}{\anotb}%=\num{0.06}
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [I don't run well,   EL=\num{\nota}
      [II run well,     EL=\num{\notab}
        [I run well  and  II run well
          [, ELT={\nota}{\notab}]
        ]
      ]
      [II don't run well,   EL=\num{\notanotb}
        [I and II don't run well
          [, ELT={\nota}{\notanotb}]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  \path ([yshift=1.5ex]current bounding box.north) coordinate (N);
  % 0.5ex can be changed to increase/decreas the vertical distance between the
  % level indicators and the tree
  \foreach \i/\j  in {3/Probability,4/Result} \node[anchor=base,font=\strut\footnotesize\sffamily] at (l-\i.center |-N){\j};
\end{forest}

\begin{forest}%
  probability tree,
  for tree={%
    anchor=west,
    child anchor=west,
  },
  [
    [I run well,     EL=\num{\a}
      [II run well,     EL=\num{\ab},
        [I and II run well,
          [,ELT={\a}{\ab} %= \num{0.14}
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [II don't run well,   EL=\num{\anotb},
        [
          I run well \\and II don't run well,
          [, ELT={\a}{\anotb}%=\num{0.06}
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [I don't run well,   EL=\num{\nota}
      [II run well,     EL=\num{\notab}
        [I run well  and  II run well
          [, ELT={\nota}{\notab}]
        ]
      ]
      [II don't run well,   EL=\num{\notanotb}
        [I and II don't run well
          [, ELT={\nota}{\notanotb}]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  \path ([yshift=1.5ex]current bounding box.north) coordinate (N);
  % 0.5ex can be changed to increase/decreas the vertical distance between the
  % level indicators and the tree
  \foreach \i/\j  in {3/Probability,4/Result} \node[anchor=base,font=\strut\footnotesize\sffamily] at (l-\i.center |-N){\j};
\end{forest}

\begin{forest}%
  probability tree,
  for descendants={
    if={>O_>{!u.n children}{1}}
    {
      forked edge,
    }{},
  },
  [
    [I run well,     EL=\num{\a}
      [II run well,     EL=\num{\ab},
        [I and II run well,
          [,ELT={\a}{\ab} %= \num{0.14}
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [II don't run well,   EL=\num{\anotb},
        [
          I run well \\and II don't run well,
          [, ELT={\a}{\anotb}%=\num{0.06}
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [I don't run well,   EL=\num{\nota}
      [II run well,     EL=\num{\notab}
        [I run well  and  II run well
          [, ELT={\nota}{\notab}]
        ]
      ]
      [II don't run well,   EL=\num{\notanotb}
        [I and II don't run well
          [, ELT={\nota}{\notanotb}]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  \path ([yshift=1.5ex]current bounding box.north) coordinate (N);
  % 0.5ex can be changed to increase/decreas the vertical distance between the
  % level indicators and the tree
  \foreach \i/\j  in {3/Probability,4/Result} \node[anchor=base,font=\strut\footnotesize\sffamily] at (l-\i.center |-N){\j};
\end{forest}


\end{document}


Why math content?
If I remove it and also all \text instructions (togwther with the braces) and replace the entry with \\ into
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}I run well \\and II don't run well\end{tabular}

the output is as expected.


The background of your MWE is not know.
Edit:
At the first version of answer I made two mistakes:

I didn't pay sufficient attention that decimal separator should be comma.
Overlooked that OP require automatic calculation of probability of each tree branch.

In the new version of MWE both issues are fixed:
Showed image (a wee bit redesigned) can recreate with the following MWE.
\documentclass[border=5pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    ELS/.style = {% Edge Label Style
                  font=\footnotesize\sffamily, inner sep=2pt,
                  anchor=#1, % label position: "ELS=north" or "ELS=south"
                  pos=0.5, sloped},
        }
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}


\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}%
TeX={%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{0.8}     \pgfmathsetmacro{\ab}{0.6}      %
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\nota}{1-\a} \pgfmathsetmacro{\notab}{1-\ab} %
    },
for tree = {
% nodes
    draw, rounded corners=2pt,
if level=0{circle}{if level=4{minimum size=13mm}
                  {inner xsep=1pt, minimum width=42mm, minimum height=13mm, align=center}},
    top color=white, bottom color=blue!20,
    anchor=center,      % <---
    child anchor=west,
if level=1{s sep= 4mm}{s sep=8mm,},% insert diferent `s sep`, 
if level=3{l sep=19mm}{l sep=11mm},% insert diferent `l sep`
% tree
      grow'=east,
      edge = {-Stealth,semithick},
      tier/.option = level,
%
/tikz/every label/.append style = {font=\strut\small\sffamily},
            },% end of tree
%%
  EL/.style = {%
    if n=1{% Edge Label, automatic positioned
    edge label={node[ELS=south]{$\num{#1}$}}}
    {edge label={node[ELS=north]{$\num{#1}$}}},
                },
ELT/.style 2 args = {%
    if n=1{% Edge Label, automatic positioned
           edge label={node[ELS=south]{$\num{#1}\times\num{#2}$}}}
          {edge label={node[ELS=north]{$\num{#1}\times\num{#2}$}}},
    if n children=0{%
      delay={content={\pgfmathparse{(#1*#2)}%
                      \num[round-precision = 2,
                           round-mode = places]{\pgfmathresult}
                     }% end of content
            }% end of delay 
                    }{},
                    },% end of ELT
[
    [I run well, EL=\a
      [II run well,     EL=\ab,
        [I and II run well, label=Probability
          [,label=Result, ELT={\a}{\ab} %= \num{0.14}
          ]
        ]
      ]
      [II don't run well,   EL=\notab,
        [
          I run well\\ and II don't run well,
          [, ELT={\a}{\notab}%=\num{0.06}
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    [I don't run well,   EL=\nota
      [II run well,     EL=\ab
        [I run well\\  and  II run well
          [, ELT={\nota}{\ab}]
        ]
      ]
      [II don't run well,   EL=\notab
        [I and II\\ don't run well
          [, ELT={\nota}{\notab}]
        ]
      ]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}

(Edit (2): in MWE is now considered @cfr comment. Now compilation of MWE is faster


I
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{0.8}  \pgfmathsetmacro{\ab}{0.6}    \pgfmathsetmacro{\notab}{0.6}  \pgfmathsetmacro{\anotb}{1-\ab}  \pgfmathsetmacro{\nota}{1-\a}  \pgfmathsetmacro{\notanotb}{1-\notab} to calculate automatically. I want to use use comma in results.

try if level=1... and if level=3... rather than parsing the tree a second and third time. (You have if earlier, so probably you lost track.) s sep'=4mm is also faster than s sep=4mm & likewise for l sep' versus l sep.

@cfr, you are right. Now I consider your suggestion. Thank you very much!

@Zarko Thank you very much.
